# Printing font change pdf

Tags: printing, fonts, pdf, evince, mendeley

When I print a PDF in (Evince) document viewer it changes the font making the document hard to read. It looks something courier but the spacing is messed up.
If I print in Mendeley the document comes out as viewed but Mendeley doesn't allow me to print double sided.

How can I

1. print double sided in Mendeley, or
2. correct the printing errors in document viewer?

Thanks. 19.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.

Mendeley follows the printer default settings but there appears to be a bug in Settings (gnome-control-center). Changing the printer settings in Settings->Printers->Printer Options; does not change the default settings for Mendeley. It does do so for Document viewer though.

Instead I had to change it in system-config-printer (Settings->Printers->Additional Printer Settings). These settings where used by Mendeley.

Additional notes on Duplex printing:

1. Duplex printing in (Evince) Document Viewer is controlled from Settings (gnome-control-center->Printers->Printer Options). The in-app duplex-settings do not work.
2. Duplex printing in Mendeley is controlled from (gnome-control-center->Printers->)Additional Printer Settings.

Comment: I have had this problem of multiple places to change printer settings before.